# Custer does not start. etcd and kube-apiserver do not start. Kubelet starts

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubeadm

After a blackout, the cluster does not start.
3 workers + 2 Control Planes.
Installed with kubeadm. Version 1.27.1
containerd 1.6.22
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
It has been running fine for more than one year, and the last kube* upgrade was 2-3 months ago.

containerd starts.
Kubelet starts, but none of the pods are launched, neither the etcd nor the kube-apiserver. So kubelet does not execute the /etc/kubernetes/manifests/*.yaml
I verified this point with crictl. The etcd and kube* pods are dated 5 weeks ago, last time, I restarted the servers. And their logs refers to the last day they ran.
Two control Planes have the same behavior, which is pretty suspicious.
I activated the debug mode and verbosity in kubelet, containerd, pods, ... Nothing clear.

I thought it was related with the network, and names resolution, because I read that kubernetes over Ubuntu can have problems with resolv.conf.
But I verified that /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml points to the correct resolv.conf.
resolvConf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

Certificates are fine.

In /run/containerd/ there is not io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri, runc nor s directories.

I checked all the logs but I do not know how to go on.
Any idea?